Laravel Model Mocking test with PHPUnit
I am trying to mock an update method in PHPUnit but so far shouldReceive('update') is not called.
PostServiceTest.php
    public function test_can_update_a_post(): void
    {
        $mockedPostModel = Post::factory()->make();
        $mockedTitle = 'Updated Title';
        $mockedSlug = Str::slug($mockedTitle);
        $mockedPostData = ['title' => $mockedTitle, 'slug' => $mockedSlug];
        $updatedPostModel = Post::factory()->make($mockedPostData);
        \Log::info($mockedPostModel);
        \Log::info($updatedPostModel);

        $postMock = Mockery::mock(Post::class);
        $postMock->shouldReceive('findOrFail')->once()->with(1)->andReturn($mockedPostModel);
        $postMock->shouldReceive('update')->once()->with($mockedPostData)->andReturn($updatedPostModel);

        $postService = new AdminPostService($postMock);
        $post = $postService->findOrFail(1);
        \Log::info($post);
        $post->update($mockedPostData);
        \Log::info($post);

        // $this->assertInstanceOf(Post::class, $post);
        // $this->assertEquals($post->title, $mockedTitle);
        // $this->assertEquals($post->slug, $mockedSlug);
    }

The logs
[2024-05-29 14:20:54] testing.INFO: {"title":"Otho Pfeffer","slug":"otho-pfeffer"}  
[2024-05-29 14:20:54] testing.INFO: {"title":"Updated Title","slug":"updated-title"}  
[2024-05-29 14:20:54] testing.INFO: {"title":"Otho Pfeffer","slug":"otho-pfeffer"}  
[2024-05-29 14:20:54] testing.INFO: {"title":"Otho Pfeffer","slug":"otho-pfeffer"}   

My expected result should be the 4th line of log should match the 2nd line of log since it is the result in $post->update($mockedPostData);
Doing $result = $post->update($mockedPostData); returns a null/blank value

I know you found a solution to your question, but you are doing it wrong, you never have to mock a model, check my profile for more info related to this. NEVER EVER mock a model

@matiaslauriti thank you for pointing that out. Fortunately, this is just my template app that I am developing. Just trying out how testing/mocking works in laravel. I will see to it that I on future mocks, model is not included. For now, I am just glad that I got it working and will use this as a reference for future mocks/testing that I will do

That is very nice, check my profile and see how to test certain stuff, it will help you a lot

Try the following:
public function test_can_update_a_post(): void
{
    $mockedPostModel = Post::factory()->make();
    $mockedTitle = 'Updated Title';
    $mockedSlug = Str::slug($mockedTitle);
    $mockedPostData = ['title' => $mockedTitle, 'slug' => $mockedSlug];
    $updatedPostModel = Post::factory()->make($mockedPostData);

    $postMock = Mockery::mock(Post::class);
    $postMock->shouldReceive('findOrFail')->once()->with(1)->andReturn($mockedPostModel);
    $postMock->shouldReceive('update')->once()->with($mockedPostData)->andReturn($updatedPostModel);

    $postService = new AdminPostService($postMock);
    $updatedPost = $postService->findOrFail(1);
    $updatedPost = $postService->update($mockedPostData); // use the same $postService for findById and update method

    $this->assertInstanceOf(Post::class, $updatedPost);
    $this->assertEquals($updatedPost->title, $updatedPostModel->title);
    $this->assertEquals($updatedPost->slug, $updatedPostModel->slug);
}

The mocked model is $postMock and used as a parameter in AdminPostService and then assigned to $postService. Meaning all the mocked methods are only accessible from $postService. Assign the result of $postService to a variable and use it in your assertions.
